# Call method from resolve to set a property value inside a service (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I go to a specific route, I'd like to run an $http request and store the result in a variable in a service.

So when I go to the '/users' route I run the UsersFactory.getUsers() method in the resolve. I want this method to run an $http request, return some users, and put those users into a property "this.usersObj" in the UsersFactory.

I'd like to do this as opposed to doing something more common like:

```
getUsers: function(UsersFactory) { return UsersFactory.getUsers(); )
```

and get that data in the controller

```
myApp.controller('UserController', function($scope, getUsers) {
  $scope.users = getUsers;
}
```

So here's what I tried:

Route File
    ...

```
  .when('/users', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
    controller : 'MyCtrl',
    resolve: {
         getUsers: ['UsersFactory', function(UsersFactory) {
           return UsersFactory.getUsers();

           // or just: UsersFactory.getUsers();
         }]
      }

...
```

Factory

```
myApp.factory('UsersFactory', 
['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

var self = this;

var getUsers = function() {
    function getUsersPromise() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: getFlashcardDecksURL
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            var users = response.data;
            deferred.resolve(users);
        }, function errorCallback() {
            deferred.reject('error msg');
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    getUsersPromise()
    .then(function successCallback(users) {
        self.usersObj = users;
    })
    .catch(function errorCallback(errorMsg) {
        self.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    });     

};

var usersObj = [];

return {
  getUsers: getUsers,
  usersObj: usersObj,
}

...
```

My attempt doesn't work. When I try to access UsersFactory.usersObj in my controller it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you are pulling the data but never returning the promise to the resolve, or returning the users from your success method. Try changing:

```
getUsersPromise()
.then(function successCallback(users) {
    self.usersObj = users;
})
.catch(function errorCallback(errorMsg) {
    self.errorMsg = errorMsg;
});
```

to:

```
return getUsersPromise()
.then(function successCallback(users) {
    self.usersObj = users;
    return self.usersObj;
})
.catch(function errorCallback(errorMsg) {
    self.errorMsg = errorMsg;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getUsers () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
    // Omitted
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    usersObj = res.data;           // Put in factory's property
    deferred.resolve(res.data);
  }, function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err)
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Basically, `resolve` will wait for your promise to be resolved. So, just return the promise and `resolve` will do the rest.